# Let $f(x)=x/6, x=1,2,3$, zero elsewhere, be the p.d.f. of $X$. Find the p.d.f. and c.d.f. of $Y=X^{2}$.

Tags: probability-theory, cumulative-distribution-functions

I don't know why, but these questions are always easier on continuous random variables...anyway, can someone please look at my solution below and see if it is correct/incorrect, especially with all the domains and such?

---

The p.d.f. of discrete $X$ is given by $$f_{X}(x) = \begin{cases} x/6, & x=1,2,3 \\ 0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

The definition of the c.d.f. of $X$ is $F_{X}(x) = \underset{x \leq w}{\sum}f_{X}(w)$. This our c.d.f. is given by $$F_{X}(x) =\begin{cases} 0, & x<1 \\ 1/6, & 1 \leq x<2\\ 3/6, & 2\leq x <3 \\ 1, & 3 \leq x
\end{cases}$$

We define $Y = X^{2}$. This $Y$ has its own space $\mathscr B = \{1, 4, 9\}$. Thus the c.d.f. of $Y$ will be found by $$F_{Y}(y) = Pr(Y \leq y) = Pr(X^{2} \leq y) = Pr(-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y})$$

But the $Pr(-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}) = F_{X}(\sqrt{y}) - F_{X}(-\sqrt{y})$ where $F_{X}(-\sqrt{y}) = 0$, and so $F_{Y}(y) = F_{X}(\sqrt{y})$ which is given by $$F_{Y}(y) = \begin{cases} 0, & y<1 \\ 1/6, & 1 \leq y<4\\ 3/6, & 4\leq y <9 \\ 1, & 9 \leq y
\end{cases}$$

Finally, the p.d.f. of $Y$ is given by $$f_{Y}(y) = \begin{cases} {\sqrt y\over 6}, & y=1,4,9 \\ 0, & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$.

---

Let me know guys, thank you!

Comment: Your $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ are probability mass functions rather than a probability density functions.  Apart from that, it all looks reasonable, though you could go directly from top to bottom without using the cumulative distribution functions: squaring $g(x)=x^2$ is an injective function on the support of $X$ i.e. $g:\{1,2,3\} \to \mathbb R$ so $f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y))$ if $y$ is in the support of $Y$

Comment: @Henry Right, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When handling change of variables for probability *mass* functions (pmf), you do not need to use cumulative distributions.   There is no scaling of density to account for; the discrete points in the support have probability mass.

$$\begin{align}f_X(x) &= \begin{cases}x/6 &:& x\in\{1,3,6\}\\[1ex]0 &:& \text{else}\end{cases}\\[3ex]f_{Y}(y) &= f_X(\surd y)&&\text{since }Y=X^2\\[1ex]&=\begin{cases}(\surd y)/6&:& \surd y\in\{1,2,3\}\\[1ex]0&:&\text{else}\end{cases}\\[1ex]&=\begin{cases}(\surd y)/6&:& y\in\{1,4,9\}\\[1ex]0&:&\text{else}\end{cases}\end{align}$$