# Finding the distribution function of a random variable 1,2,...,16

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Find the distribution function of a random variable taking the values ​​1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 (without 9!) with the same probably. Write down the value of this function at x=15.1

Could you give me an advice?

$F_X(x)=\frac{1}{15}$, since there 15 numbers with equal probability

Comment: $P(X=15.1)=0$, since $x$ is not in the domain of the distribution function.

Comment: @callculus42: thank you for your respond. As example, I want find P(X=13.1), then as there are 15 numbers and the same probability, then $F_X(x)=\frac{1}{15}$ and $P(X=13.1)=12/15$, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Your notation is not right: $F_X(x)$ is for the cdf and $f_X(x)$ is for the pmf. In both cases you have to write it, as it is usually written.  [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4297074/let-fx-x-6-x-1-2-3-zero-elsewhere-be-the-p-d-f-of-x-find-the-p-d-f-a) is an example. The p.m.f. of discrete $X$ is given by $$f_{X}(x) = \begin{cases} x/6, & x=1,2,3 \\ 0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

$F_{X}(x) = \underset{x \leq w}{\sum}f_{X}(w)$. This our c.d.f. is given by $$F_{X}(x) =\begin{cases} 0, & x<1 \\ 1/6, & 1 \leq x<2\\ 3/6, & 2\leq x <3 \\ 1, & 3 \leq x
\end{cases}$$